# How can I execute the second function?

Tags: python

I have connected a heart rate sensor correctly to a Raspberry Pi.

now:[The program runs without errors, but the second function(send_data) does not work.]

The first function:Reads sensor values.
The second function: sending data.

The sensor works properly. But the sensor data is not sent and the second function does not work.
I have put in a lot of effort to be able to solve this problem.

'''

```
import requests
import time
import Adafruit_ADS1x15

thingspeak_key = "API_KEY" 

class hr:
    def __init__(self):

        adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1015()
        GAIN = 2/3  
        curState = 0
        thresh = 525  
        P = 512
        T = 512
        stateChanged = 0
        sampleCounter = 0
        lastBeatTime = 0
        firstBeat = True
        secondBeat = False
        Pulse = False
        IBI = 600
        rate = [0]*10
        amp = 100

        lastTime = int(time.time()*1000)

        while True:
            Signal = adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN)   
            curTime = int(time.time()*1000)

            sampleCounter += curTime - lastTime;      
            lastTime = curTime
            N = sampleCounter - lastBeatTime;    

            if Signal < thresh and N > (IBI/5.0)*3.0 :  
                if Signal < T :                     
                  T = Signal;                       

            if Signal > thresh and  Signal > P:          
                P = Signal;                             
                                         
            if N > 250 :                                  
                if  (Signal > thresh) and  (Pulse == False) and  (N > (IBI/5.0)*3.0)  :       
                  Pulse = True;                               
                  IBI = sampleCounter - lastBeatTime;         
                  lastBeatTime = sampleCounter;               

                  if secondBeat :                        
                    secondBeat = False;                 
                    for i in range(0,10):             
                      rate[i] = IBI;                      

                  if firstBeat :                        
                    firstBeat = False;                  
                    secondBeat = True;                  
                    continue                            

                  runningTotal = 0;               

                  for i in range(0,9):                
                    rate[i] = rate[i+1];               
                    runningTotal += rate[i];            

                  rate[9] = IBI;                          
                  runningTotal += rate[9];              
                  runningTotal /= 10;                    
                  BPM = 60000/runningTotal;               
                  self.data_hr=str(BPM)
                  print ('BPM: {}'.format(self.data_hr))

            if Signal < thresh and Pulse == True :   
                Pulse = False;                      
                amp = P - T;                           
                thresh = amp/2 + T;             
                P = thresh;                           
                T = thresh;

            if N > 2500 :                      
                thresh = 512;                        
                P = 512;                            
                T = 512;                            
                lastBeatTime = sampleCounter;           
                firstBeat = True;                     
                secondBeat = False;                 
                print ("no beats found")
    def send_data(self):
        
        r = requests.post('https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=API_KEY', data = {'api_key':thingspeak_key, 'field1':format(self.data_hr)})
        
        time.sleep(0.005)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x=hr()
    x.self.send_data()
```

'''

Comment: Hello and welcome to this site! Please do be careful to not post your API keys online, as it is relatively sensitive information and can be copied and used by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is coming from:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  __init__("self")
```

You're trying to call the constructor of the class directly, and python doesn't know what `__init__` is outside of the class that it has been defined in because of it's local scope. Also, `"self"` is a string, not an object.

You can just replace this with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    heartrate = hr()
```

This creates an object and calls the constructor as well. You don't need to add `self` because python already knows what the class constructor is referring to.

However, you'll get stuck in your while loop in your `hr` class constructor, so I suggest splitting your constructor (the `__init__` function) into separate functions and calling them separately.

Comment: Hello dear friend, thank you. I did this for you, but this error occurs. [ x=hr() NameError: name 'hr' is not defined ]

Comment: @aminsadati that's because you do it inside the class itself. The `if __name__` block should be in the global scope. No offense, but it looks like you should go over some tutorials

Comment: Thanks. The program runs without errors, but the second function(send_data) does not work.

Comment: @aminsadati You're welcome :) Please mark this question as accepted if it helped you. As for your second error it would be best if you made a separate question for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `"self"` to `__init__`, and hence your `self` variable is becoming a string.

A better way would be to do the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
 x = hr()
 x.send_data()
```

Also, you might want to create different functions rather than doing everything in `init`.

Comment: Hello dear friend, thank you. I did this for you, but this error occurs.

[  x=hr()
NameError: name 'hr' is not defined   ]

Comment: Hi. I made an error in the comment I had posted. Fixed it now. It would be `x.send_data()` rather than `hr.send_data()`

Comment: hi,Thanks. The program runs without errors, but the second function(send_data) does not work.

Comment: When you say doesn't work, what error do you get? Because `x.send_data()` would call your send_data method.

Comment: hi.It does not give an error. But the second function(send_data) does not work and the data is not sent.

Comment: Without an explicit error, it is not possible for us to help. If no explicit error is thrown, then send_data method is being called properly. Any issue then might be with the post request that you are sending or the server than is waiting for the requests. You can debug these two things.

Comment: Hello.Thank you for following up.I'm sure the problem is not either. 
(post request, the server than is waiting for the requests.)